# fluid dynamics- is this flow incompressible?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I have been given a flow with Lagrange path trajectories:
$$x(\alpha,t)=(\alpha_1\cos(t)+\alpha_2\sin(t),\alpha_2\cos(t)-\alpha_1\sin(t),\alpha_3)$$ and I have to determine whether it is an incompressible flow or not. I know that incompressible flow means its mass density is always constant along a particle path, which leads to the statement that the material derivative of the density equals zero, and hence the divergence of the velocity function equals zero, or:
$$\nabla \cdotp v=0$$
and so I worked out the Lagrangian velocity of the fluid: $$v(\alpha,t)=(-\alpha_1\sin(t)+\alpha_2\cos(t),-\alpha_2\sin(t)-\alpha_1\cos(t),0)$$
and then calculated the divergence of $v$, which gave:
$$\nabla \cdotp v=-2sin(t)$$
which is not equal to zero, and hence the fluid is incompressible. Is this correct? I get a sense from the question that the fluid IS incompressible and I could have done this completely wrong, so I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** you have to find an expression $v(x)$ instead of $v(t)$: the divergence operator
is applied to spacial variables.

details:$$
v(x) = (y,-x,0)\\
\nabla\cdot v = \partial_x y  + \partial_y(-x) + \partial_z(0)= 0+0+0=0
$$

Comment: makes sense... thank you!